# Select was changed to select2 and broke my dropdown list test

Tags: selenium

Getting error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

```
   public analyticsLandingPage verifyReportingProfile() throwsInterruptedException{
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("select2-choice")));

    select.selectByVisibleText("Arria");

    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsLandingPage.class);
}
```

This is my HTML page:

```
 <div id="s2id_reporting_profile_id" class="select2-container select2-allowclear reporting_profile select2-container-active" 
  style="width: 50%;">
  <a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
 <span id="select2-chosen-7" class="select2-chosen">AdOps Reporting Profile</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
```

How can I make it work ? I need it to click on dropdown list and select element. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is caused because you have to click a button on the front-end before Selenium can register the dropdown.  A lot of times this is caused by a javascript call.  Have you tried clicking on the div:

```
id="s2id_reporting_profile_id"
```

And then clicking on the select2-choice option?

It could also be this:

```
select.selectByVisibleText("Arria");
```

Is there text visible on that element after you click it?  Or does another element show up from `href="javascript:void(0)"` when select gets clicked?  If that's the case you need to click it in Selenium.

If this doesn't help, your question is very vague, maybe you could edit it to have it make more sense?  Help us help you trouble shoot the problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help, i fixed it